# ls it possible to construct discrete r.v.s given expectation and variance?

Tags: random-variables, variance, expected-value

Suppose there is a discrete r.v.s X, all we know is:
E(X) = 10 and VAR(X) = 2500

Any general way to find PMF of X?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean and variance do not completely determine the pmf. There are infinitely many pmfs's with mean $10$ and variance $2500$. To find on example of such a pmf you take a random variable taking two values $a$ and $b$ with probability $\frac 1 2$ each and solve for $a$ and $b$ from the given conditions. This gives $P(X=60)=P(X=-40)=\frac  1 2$.